# Использую часы но они в формате 12

Tags: java, android

Как сделать формат часов 24?
Использую часы от [Material DateTime Picker](http://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker).
Там ни слова об этом

```
  btnvaxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar now1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                       elaqemesage.this,
                        now1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        now1.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        false

                );
                tpd.setAccentColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
                tpd.setTitle("Tarixi Seçin ");
                tpd.setOkText("Ok");
                tpd.setCancelText("Geriyə");
            }
        });
```

---

```
public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
        String time = ""+hourOfDay+":"+minute;
        timeTextView.setText(time);
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте код, который вы используете

Comment: только что добаил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                       elaqemesage.this,
                        now1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        now1.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        true)// boolean is24HourMode
```

Comment: аааа спасибо добрая душа значит булиан определят 12 или 24?

Comment: @elik, судя из названия аргумента, да.